# Rails how to find where enum is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

I recently got the error:

```
You tried to define an enum named "label_type" on the model "Spree::ShippingMethod", but this will generate a instance method "label_type=", which is already defined by another enum.
```

The backtrace gives me the location of the enum that I attempted to define second, but not the first enum that was defined. Grepping through my codebase only brings up the file in the backtrace, so I suspect it's in a gem, but I don't how to find which gem it's in.

To be clear, I'm aware that the error I gave means that the enum has already been defined somewhere else. In the course of fixing this problem, I'm trying to figure out where it was defined.

Comment: probably it's gem spree, could you provide your Gemfile?

Comment: @AzatGataoulline No, I have all of spree (main gems + extensions) in the same directory loaded locally, so they were scanned along with the rest of my code. Gemfile: https://gist.github.com/Shelvetco/0d2466ed8f9063faaf12

Answer (score 1):

It might be defined in a gem. It could be defined through meta-programming. Maybe you can find out more with the help of *Pry*:

- add 'pry' to your Gemfile (and run bundle install)
- place "binding.pry" in the ruby code, just before the location where the error occurs
- run the application. It will stop at the binding.pry command.
- At the pry prompt, type `show-method label_type=`
- type `exit-p` or `!!!` to leave *pry* when done.

Comment: unfortunately it just points to `active_record/enum.rb`. Good idea though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have column or instance method label_type in that model. Basically when you define enum on a column it will create read/write method for setting that column value. FYI: Please refer this page http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: I know this. The question I asked is how do I find where it was first defined?

Comment: When when define enum inside the model then automatically read/write methods created. Please check here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6dfab475ca230dfcad7a603483431c8e7a8f908e/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L146

Comment: Please see the edit to my question. This does not answer my question.